# reading and copying lines of text in a specific way

Tags: c#, loops, read-write

I have five lines of text in a text file that I want to read and write in the following way:

1. read 1st line and copy it to new text file 1.
2. read 1st and 2nd line and copy them to new text file 2.
3. read 1st, 2nd and 3rd line and copy them to new text file 3.
4. read 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th line and copy them to new text file 4.
5. read all lines and copy them to new text file 5.

I have tried something with loops, but I just get confused. Or maybe to use recursion....?

Comment: If you've tried something, then show the code. It helps explain what you're trying to do and where you're going wrong.

Comment: Loops and recursion are pretty much the same thing in principle, so that shouldn't be anything you'd need to think about. In any case, SO is not a homework-writing service, so I'm affraid this is off-topic here.

Comment: Why don't you read all lines into an array of strings and then just print what you need. This is basically the famous http://madhveshbhalodia.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/1-12-123-1234-12345.html

Comment: Yeah, that totally worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Something like that (just *Linq* with `Take`)

```
// ..Or ReadAllLines to cache the file lines
var source = File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyText.txt");

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\target1.txt", source.Take(1));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\target2.txt", source.Take(2));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\target3.txt", source.Take(3));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\target4.txt", source.Take(4));

// not 5 lines, but entire file
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\target5.txt", source);
```

Comment: I like the usage of take, never heard of it. But i really don't like that mass of code duplication.. :D

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic solution for you.. Please check for the rest, this is just for help you out.

```
List<String> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\m\Desktop\te\source.txt").ToList();
string basicPath = @"C:\Users\m\Desktop\te\";

int i = 1;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(basicPath + i + ".txt", lines.GetRange(0, i));
    i++;
}
```